# Connecting a shopping cart "total price" attribute to a payments configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway, shopping-cart, product

I am starting to put together an application that includes, products, a shopping cart and payments. You start by adding the product to your cart by going to /products. Then if you navigate to /cart the system will populate your list of products ready to checkout. The plan is to link the "total price" attribute within the carts table into the payments table.

How do I go about linking two attributes from separate tables to make them the same? I have marked the two attributes that need to be the same, "total price" and "amount."

create_payments.rb

```
class CreatePayments < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :payments do |t|
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
    t.string :last4
    ***t.decimal :amount, precision: 12, scale: 3***
    t.boolean :success
    t.string :authorization_code

    t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

create_order_items.rb

```
class CreateOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :order_items do |t|
    t.references :product, index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.references :order, index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.decimal :unit_price, precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.integer :quantity
    ***t.decimal :total_price, precision: 12, scale: 3***

    t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Please let me know if any further files will be needed to help troubleshoot the problem. Thank you in advance for any type of assistance!

Comment: what do you exactly mean by same?

Comment: I basically want to replace the "amount" attribute from the payments table with the "total_price" attribute from the order_items table. So when a user makes a payment, it populates the amount owed based off the product purchased.

Comment: I think you need to have a `belongs_to` reference to your `Order` inside your `payments` and a `has_one` inside your payment. that way you can simply grab the price of all the `OrderItems` and populate the `amount` attribute like. `payment.amount = payment.order.order_items.select("total_price").reduce(&:+)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for here is to write a custom "getter" method, i.e. a virtual attribute. You could also overwrite `save` or use an (activerecord callback)[http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html]

For example:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items

  # --------
  # option 1
  # --------

  def amount
    # sums up the total price of the associated order items
    self.order_items.pluck(:price).sum
  end

  # --------
  # option 2
  # --------

  def save(*args)
    self.amount = self.order_items.pluck(:price).sum
    super(*args)
  end

  # ----------
  # option 3
  # ----------

  before_save :set_amount
  def set_amount
    self.amount = self.order_items.pluck(:price).sum
  end

end
```

with the first option ("custom getter"), the aggregate column is not stored in the database and is dynamically recalculated each time it's value is accessed.

With the second option ("overriding save"), the `amount` column will be automatically set whenever `save` is called on a record.

The third option is probably the best in my opinion. It basically does the same thing as option 2, but looks a little cleaner.